# Git log to get the files list, which are deleted and not currently present in local repository

Tags: git

I need a git command to list all files between range of commits in two dates, but it should not list the files deleted and currently not present in the local repository.

My Ultimate aim is to identify the list of files modified, added, changed and modified between the two dates range, it should not display the files which are deleted and not currently present in the local repository.

```
git log --pretty="format:" --name-only  --since "06/10/2015" --until "05/19/2016" --diff-filter=AM* | sort -u | grep .java
```

The above command did not work, as it considered for the file even deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --diff-filter=D --pretty="format:" --name-only --since "06/10/2015" --until "05/19/2016" --diff-filter=AM* | sort -u | grep -.java
```

Brings a list of deleted files in that timeframe. Subtract that list from your previous results. I don't know if diff-filter can handle a NOT operation. Cursory glance at docs says no.